# SQL naming convention: Adding data type to column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

As a developer, a common mistake that I keep on repeating is assuming the data type of a column. I have read multiple articles regarding SQL column naming convention but have not seen any reference regarding data type as part of the column name - specifically for SQL Server.

E.g. Revenue_f for float, Organization_v for varchar, AccountNumber_i for integer and so on.

This must have been thought of already before but I want to know the reason why it is not being used, or an expert's input regarding the matter; pointing me to the right article/documentations will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can apply that rule in your own code if you want but what is the point exactly?  Usually you can tell by the way a field is named what its type is.  If you are not sure just look at the schema.

Comment: This is probably going to be seen as off topic for StackOverflow; naming convention is something that is extremely opinionated. Some places do actually have practices like that, where as others don't; you often see suffixes on objects to denote their type. Doing so on a column isn't as good an idea, as if you change the properties of the column the name may no longer be correct. (i.e. changing from an `int` to `decimal`). it's unlikely, however, that an SP is going to change to a Table (although I've seen tables change to views). The important part of naming conventions is consistency though.

Comment: If you want to discuss this in an environment it's not seen as off topic, you'll probably be better on [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Larnu Thank you, both you and Sean have been very helpful and apologies for mistaking this as a valid question - will be careful next time.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it wasn't a valid question, per say, just that the answers to the way it's worded would be very opinionated. If you want to discuss things in an opinionated perspective, SO isn't the right place. It all depends how you word the question as well. A question can be less opinionated if the question is more closed; very open ended questions are more likely to have opinionated answers, as they;re open to interpretation and thus personal opinion will be involved. :)

Comment: This is why I recommended DBA, as one of the things you can ask about there is: *Data Modelling and database-design, including referential-integrity*. naming convention certainly falls under the database design side of things. [dba.se - Asking](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a horrible naming convention. Consider how awful it would be if you need to change AccountNumber to a character datatype. Do you then go back and rename the column and change every single query everywhere? Or do you leave the suffix in your column name even though it is no longer accurate? If you want to know the datatype of a column the ONLY way is to look at the definition of the table.

Also, a single character really is kind of useless. How do you handle nvarchar vs varchar? And what about the scale?

P.S. Even though I wrote an answer I am voting to close this question because it is primarily opinion based and as such is considered off topic for SO.

Comment: Never thought of it in that perspective... thank you! Won't be needing the scale since error happens in our extract and transform stage where we try to keep everything doubtful to nvarchar/varchar in staging as to avoid errors in pulling data - obviously causing conversion errors. Anyway, this has been very helpful.